# How to get delta from audio.currentTime?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, audio, three.js

I want to tie my Three.js skeletal animation to an audio track. Normally, to animate the model, I would do:

```
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

function animate(){
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    THREE.AnimationHandler.update(delta);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

But now I have an HTML5 audio object that I want to use from which I can get `audio.currentTime`, but what is the best way to translate that into a delta that the animation will understand?

Is it just a matter of saving `audio.currentTime` off to a variable outside of the animation function and then subtracting it from the new `audio.currentTime` or does there need to be more logic than that? Like what happens  if the user rewinds the track a bit? Would/should the delta be negative and can THREE.AnimationHandler handle that or do I need to do a `Math.max(delta, 0)` or something?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: @Andreas, I did. It appears to work, but I don't know if this is the right way to do it or not.

Comment: answer updated a while ago, is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Unverified : from the documentation, `THREE.AnimationHandler.update` needs milliseconds. Using a delta from the audio value should not work because it should return a ratio, not the time in milliseconds.

---

The best solution, that also fits cases where you would change `audio.currentTime`, is to use the `currentTime` property of the `THREE.Animation` class.

So you could simply write in the render loop :

```
    myAnimation.currentTime = audio.currentTime ;
```

Comment: Please see the answer I posted. It appears to work. I'm not sure what you mean by the audio returning a "ratio". I can't use your solution of using the animation.currentTime because I have multiple animations playing one after the other on a timeline.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was this:

```
var previousTime = 0;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    var currentTime = audio.currentTime;
    var delta = currentTime - previousTime;
    previousTime = currentTime;

    THREE.AnimationHandler.update(delta);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

What I don't know is if this will have any side effects that I'm not aware of. Please let me know if that's the case. Thanks.